# What is the most effective method to create a user in Xubuntu who inherits all customizations of the system?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, users, user-management

After installing an Xubuntu system on a computer, it is advisable to create separate user accounts different from the account with admin rights resulting from the installation itself.

But some basic settings are less than optimum after installation, etc:

- I want to lock the keys CapsLock and Insert (what is the overtype mode good for? It only creates trouble, like CapsLock) and the key combinations Alt-delete and Alt-insert (delete or create additional workplace),
- In the terminal's settings, the color for highlighted text is dark
  and with very low contrast to the black background, I also want to be
  able to roll back say 6000 lines, the size of a newly opened terminal
  should also be broader, say 130 characters,
- Thunar should always begin in the details view, Catfish shall be
  installed and be callable from Thunar, the columns should be in this order: size,
  change date, name, owner, group, access rights, display the dates in
  ISO form rather today/yesterday and so on.
- I want different themes and finetunings for the desktop,
- associate a couple of shortcuts for screenshots (with rectangular
  range, active window, full screen, full screen - delayed, screenshot
  to file with automatic name in ISO date format)
- Install some essential plugins into Firefox (uBlock origin, no
  Script, New Tab Redirect, Tab Cookie Remover, KeePassXC Browser) and
  apply some settings to it,
- Increase the number of work spaces to two, install a workspace
  switcher and some other tools on the task bar, configure meters for
  network activity, cpu/memory/swap usage and so on.
- The settings for automatically started programs shall become effective for other users.

All these configuration steps leave their traces somewhere in or below  `/home/<installation user>/.config`. Cloning this whole directory to a second, third, ... user has the disadvantage that there are quite some references in the cloned files which have to be adapted from `/home/<installation user>` to `/home/<second user and so on>`. Also cloning has to be done with `sudo` from a command line or by calling `pkexec thunar`. The copied `.config` and all its content belong to `root:root` then and this has to be mended also.

**Is there a more elegant way which is recommended for configuring subsequent user accounts after Installation avoiding repetitive work for each of them?**

**Or has someone already made a script which performs all the adaptations in configuration files exchanging the installation user to the to be configured new user?** (see above what has to be done).

Comment: Silly question, but are these separate user accounts for other people, or for you to use without access to `sudo`? 

Comment: Why is this question stupid? As far as I can tell at the moment, my question gives reason to think about how to simplify the setup of multiple accounts with certain basic settings. Immediately after installation, not all of them are really practical, see above! In my question I already touched on some technical details. Real answers would give even more hints how to configure a freshly installed system in a useful way right away, without going through all the individual setting steps! I expect them to be especially interesting in the commercial Linux environment!

Comment: Both cases happen: If I install a computer for myself, it has two separate accounts: one for administration (among the sudoers) and a normal user account for everyday's work (not among the sudoers). If I install a computer for friends, they often ask me to create more than one normal account for other family members. So there are lots of applications for good answers.